# Trouble installing Mechanize with Strawberry (portable) Perl (for Windows 7)

Tags: windows, perl, mechanize, portability

I've seen posts elsewhere on Stack Overflow suggesting that the sort of problem I have installing Mechanize for use with Strawberry Perl occur due to corporate firewalls, but I am *not* behind a corporate firewall. I do use an ISP modem and I have anti-virus software installed on my desktop. How should I configure cpan to avoid this problem?

```
----------------------------------------------
 Welcome to Strawberry Perl Portable Edition!
 * URL - http://www.strawberryperl.com/
 * see README.TXT for more info
----------------------------------------------
Perl executable: C:\portableperl\perl\bin\perl.exe
Perl version   : 5.18.2 / MSWin32-x64-multi-thread


C:\portableperl>cpan WWW:Mechanize
CPAN: CPAN::SQLite loaded ok (v0.203)
CPAN: LWP::UserAgent loaded ok (v6.05)
CPAN: Time::HiRes loaded ok (v1.9726)
Fetching with LWP:
http://cpan.strawberryperl.com/authors/01mailrc.txt.gz
LWP failed with code[500] message[Can't connect to cpan.strawberryperl.com:80 (B
ad hostname)]
Warning: no success downloading 'C:\portableperl\cpan\sources\authors\01mailrc.t
xt.gz.tmp2828'. Giving up on it.
Fetching with LWP:
http://www.cpan.org/authors/01mailrc.txt.gz
LWP failed with code[500] message[Can't connect to www.cpan.org:80 (Bad hostname
)]
Warning: no success downloading 'C:\portableperl\cpan\sources\authors\01mailrc.t
xt.gz.tmp2828'. Giving up on it.
Fetching with LWP:
http://www.cpan.org/authors/01mailrc.txt.gz
LWP failed with code[500] message[Can't connect to www.cpan.org:80 (Bad hostname
)]
Warning: no success downloading 'C:\portableperl\cpan\sources\authors\01mailrc.t
xt.gz.tmp2828'. Giving up on it.
Warning: no success downloading 'C:\portableperl\cpan\sources\authors\01mailrc.t
xt.gz.tmp2828'. Giving up on it.
No external ftp command available

Fetching with LWP:
http://cpan.strawberryperl.com/authors/01mailrc.txt.gz
LWP failed with code[500] message[Can't connect to cpan.strawberryperl.com:80 (B
ad hostname)]
Warning: no success downloading 'C:\portableperl\cpan\sources\authors\01mailrc.t
xt.gz.tmp2828'. Giving up on it.
Fetching with LWP:
http://www.cpan.org/authors/01mailrc.txt.gz
LWP failed with code[500] message[Can't connect to www.cpan.org:80 (Bad hostname
)]
Warning: no success downloading 'C:\portableperl\cpan\sources\authors\01mailrc.t
xt.gz.tmp2828'. Giving up on it.
Fetching with LWP:
http://www.cpan.org/authors/01mailrc.txt.gz
LWP failed with code[500] message[Can't connect to www.cpan.org:80 (Bad hostname
)]
Warning: no success downloading 'C:\portableperl\cpan\sources\authors\01mailrc.t
xt.gz.tmp2828'. Giving up on it.
Warning: no success downloading 'C:\portableperl\cpan\sources\authors\01mailrc.t
xt.gz.tmp2828'. Giving up on it.
No external ftp command available

CPAN: YAML::XS loaded ok (v0.41)
Please check, if the URLs I found in your configuration file
(http://cpan.strawberryperl.com/, http://www.cpan.org/,
http://www.cpan.org/) are valid. The urllist can be edited. E.g. with 'o
conf urllist push ftp://myurl/'

Could not fetch authors/01mailrc.txt.gz


C:\portableperl>
```

Comment: Try `ping cpan.strawberryperl.com` and `ping www.cpan.org` in your command window

Comment: C:\Users\JGS>ping cpan.strawberryperl.com
   
Pinging cpan.strawberryperl.com [69.163.179.35] with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 69.163.179.35: bytes=32 time=64ms TTL=56
Reply from 69.163.179.35: bytes=32 time=64ms TTL=56
Reply from 69.163.179.35: bytes=32 time=64ms TTL=56
Reply from 69.163.179.35: bytes=32 time=62ms TTL=56

Ping statistics for 69.163.179.35:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 62ms, Maximum = 64ms, Average = 63ms

Comment: C:\Users\JGS>ping www.cpan.org

    Pinging cpan-global.l.develooper.org [207.171.7.91] with 32 bytes of data:
    Reply from 207.171.7.91: bytes=32 time=64ms TTL=55
    Reply from 207.171.7.91: bytes=32 time=63ms TTL=55
    Reply from 207.171.7.91: bytes=32 time=62ms TTL=55
    Reply from 207.171.7.91: bytes=32 time=62ms TTL=55

    Ping statistics for 207.171.7.91:
        Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
    Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
        Minimum = 62ms, Maximum = 64ms, Average = 62ms
    
    C:\Users\JGS>

Answer (score 1):

Given the list of error messages:

```
LWP failed with code[500] message[Can't connect to cpan.strawberryperl.com:80 (Bad hostname)]
LWP failed with code[500] message[Can't connect to www.cpan.org:80 (Bad hostname)]
```

I would suggest that it's either a problem with your internet connection, your firewall, or permissions that you're giving cpan.

I suspect that you can probably reach either of the two above urls via a web browser.

Try running cmd prompt as administrator, and try again.

Comment: Yes, I am able to access both websites in a browser (although the first one redirects). I get the same results running as administrator, but after starting a cmd shell with administrator privilege, I launch the strawberry .bat file and perhaps it does not inherit those permissions. I know nothing about cmd execution context.

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved. It was the damn anti-virus software running on my machine!!!!